# should I bind some port for UDP client?

Tags: python, sockets, server, udp, client

What I'm doing is that: I start two servers, server1 and server2, and start only one client.

- server1: will always forward the received request(in this request, the original client address is included) to server2
- server2: will make a response back to the original client
- client: will send a request to server1

As a result, when server1, server2 and client are running in the same host but with different port, this works(the client can receive msg from server2). But when servers and client are in two different hosts, the client can't receive any response from server2 while keeping waiting for the reply.

One more thing, when I bind client with some port, everything is okay. Why?

```py
# code for client
import argparse
import socket,sys

def _parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("host", type=str, nargs=1, help="the host")
    parser.add_argument("port", type=int, nargs=1, help="the port")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args.host[0], args.port[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host, port = _parse_args()
    destination         = (host, port);
    s     = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM);
    sentBytesCount      = s.sendto("send something".encode(), destination);
    while True:
        print ('waiting')
        try:
            receivedBytes = s.recvfrom(4096)
            print (receivedBytes)
            print(receivedBytes[0].decode())
            print ('done')
        except:
            print ("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
            s.close()
        break
    s.close()
```

```py
# code for server1
import socket
import random,sys


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM);
s.bind(("ip1", p1));
while(True):
    req, cli_addr = s.recvfrom(4096);
    cli_host = cli_addr[0]
    cli_port = cli_addr[1]
    print (type(cli_host))
    print ("recv req from:", cli_host, cli_port)
    print ("req is:", req.decode())
    print ("forward this req to:",("ip1", p2))
    try:
        s.sendto((cli_host + ',' + str(cli_port)).encode(), ("ip1", p2));
        #s.sendto(("I'm server1").encode(), (cli_host, cli_port));
    except:
        print ("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        s.close()
        raise
    print ('successfully forward req')
```

```py
# code for server2
import socket
import random

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM);
s.bind(("ip1", p2));
while(True):
    req, cli_addr = s.recvfrom(4096);
    cli_host = cli_addr[0]
    cli_port = cli_addr[1]
    print ("recv req from:", cli_host, cli_port)
    req = req.decode()
    ori_cli_host = req.split(',')[0]
    ori_cli_port = int(req.split(',')[1])
    try:
        print ('origin client is:', ori_cli_host, ori_cli_port)
        x = s.sendto(("I'm server2").encode(), (ori_cli_host, ori_cli_port));
        print (x)
    except:
        print ("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        s.close()
        raise
    print ('successfully send resp to:',(ori_cli_host, ori_cli_port))
```

Comment: I don't see any client code with `bind()`? Not that you should have.

Comment: @Torxed Hi, servers are bound to p1 / p2. I think we don't need to bind a port for client explicitly. Right?

Comment: Servers need to bind to a local port, it's just to tell the underlying socket layer that "hi, I'm responsible for this port". Other than that, no you don't need to bind anything else.

Comment: @Torxed Yep. I do bind ports for servers. The problem is that if I don't bind a port explicitly for client, the client can't receive the response from server2; If bind some sport, the client can get the reply from server2. Just like what I said in the above description. Wonder why this happens like this?

Comment: You never send anything to server2, so how would you expect to receive something? I know UDP isn't session based, but the underlaying socket layer needs some form of indication or setup of the pipeline in order to send/recieve data. I *miiiight* be wrong here, I'd have to double check. But last time the abstraction layer of the socket layer will need a "session" even tho it's not TCP for this to work. You can use raw-sockets to send and recieve as you choose, but as this is an abstraction, some rules apply.

Comment: @Torxed Thanks for info. By the way, just like the code shown above, the server1(with p1) will send a message to server2(with p2). Does it make sense?

Comment: Sure but you never return the data to the client. But if you're only interested in `client -> s1 -> s2` that's fine, because `s2` won't be able to respond to `client` since there's no session between `client` and `s2`. I'm speculating now as I've never done this with a UDP stream before heh. I'm guessing tho that the lower socket layer will look at this and discard it because there's no "hidden session" between the two IP's and thus assume it's not meant for this socket setup. Easy fix would be to send a dummy packet from `client` to `s2` on the same source port, not sure how tho.

Comment: @Torxed Yeah, you maybe right. There isn't session between `client` and `s2`(But `s2` will send a message to `client`). The interesting thing is that if I bind the `client` with some port explicitly, then the `client` can receive the message sent from `s2`; If the client isn't bound explicitly, the client can't get the message sent from `s2`. This is the most confusing place for now.

Comment: That's because you're essentially turning the client into a server :P I mean you can do that, it's just not how communication normally goes. But you can. Just don't expect support on odd edge cases not working ^^